# Analogs of Wigner-Eckart theorem for other groups

Tags: integration, representation-theory, lie-groups, rotations, symmetry

**Question:** Are there analogs of the [Wigner-Eckart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Eckart_theorem) theorem for continuous groups other than $SO(3)$?

Some motivation: In quantum mechanics, one often uses parity or Wigner-Eckart to evaluate the various integrals that arise in e.g. atomic transition amplitudes.  If parity and rotational symmetry can be used to simplify integrals, it would surprise me if this were not true of other groups, too.

Comment: Technically, the group is $\text{SU}(2)$, and, due to the Peter-Weyl theorem, I think instead of this group we could have any compact group.

Answer (score 3):

1. For compact groups see Theorem 2 on page 247 of

A. Barut, and R. Razka. Theory of Group Representations and Applications. Singapore, World Scientific Publishing, 1986.

2. For locally compact groups, see

A. U. Klimyk, Wigner–Eckart theorem for locally compact groups. Theor. Math.
Phys. 8 (1971), p. 668–672.